# Empty keywords fields after migration from CVS to GIT using cvs2git

Tags: git, migration, cvs, cvs2git

I am migrating many repositories from CVS to GIT. I used cvs gitimport first, but it didn't work properly. cvs2git works (almost) fine. 
Unfortunately there is one issue that worked in cvs gitimport and does not work in cvs2git (and is important for me)
After migration using cvs2git, fields containing keywords (in specific files) are empty:

---

$Header$

$Revision$

$Author$

$Date$

"filename" Revision: 1.2

---

I tried different configurations of:
ctx.revision_collector, ctx.revision_reader,_keyword_handling but the effect is still the same.

The main commands I used:

cvs2git --blobfile=cvs2git-tmp/${module}-tmp/git-blob.dat --dumpfile=cvs2git-tmp/${module}-tmp/git-dump.dat --username=migrationuser --encoding=ascii --encoding=utf8 --encoding=cp1250 --encoding=iso8859_2 --fallback-encoding=ascii --retain-conflicting-attic-files ${module}

git --bare init "projectname"
  cd "projectname"
  cat ../../cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat ../../cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat | git fast-import
  git branch -D TAG.FIXUP
  git gc --prune=now
  git repack -a -d -f

Has anyone managed to solve such a problem? Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: CVS-style keywords are a bad idea and Git deliberately has really bad support for them. Before you investigate redoing your conversion with keyword expansion turned on (I'm not sure how to do that, it's been at least a decade since I used cvs2git), be *really sure* you would like to fight with Git about this.

Comment: the keywords modify the file contents. git will see the files as modified after the keywords are substituted. Potentially you can write your own checker for updated files which will ignore substituted keywords and several git hooks to handle them on the way in and out and merge and rebase, .... It does not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the `cvsconvert` program from my fork of [cvs-fast-export](https://gitlab.com/robo-hack/cvs-fast-export.git)  (The original version now mistakenly blindly uses `-kb` to check out revisions, but that's entirely unlike what CVS normally does!)

My version currently does not pass any `-k` option, so mostly expands keywords as a CVS user would expect them to be expanded.

Once you've converted to Git, IFF you want to continue using per-file keyword expansion then you might consider using Git's `$Format:$` feature which is enabled by setting the `export-subst` attribute for all files needing such expansions, and generating your releases with [git-archive(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#ATTRIBUTES).  Note these are only expanded when the release is created with `git archive`, but generally that's when they're most useful anyway.

For example I replace my old occurrences of `$Id$` or `$CVSHeader$` with something like the following (adapted where necessary for different comment or string constant syntax, and of course with the actual project name and file path):

```
#ident  "@(#)PROJECT:FILEPATH:$Format:%D:%ci:%cN:%h$"
```